# Receiving binary data over HTTP

Tags: java, http, post, png

I have a server which is sending a .png image to a client via a HTTP post request. The .png is stored inside a sqlite3 database, retrieved as a blob and this all works fine; I have tested saving the returned blob to disk and it can be opened as expected. When my client interprets the response, the payload has mysteriously grown in length from 16365 to 16367, inspecting the response string has shown there are some extra '?' characters intermittently in the stream

Testing the server using the ARC plug-in for Chrome has shown the response received there to be the right length, which leads me to believe there is a problem with my client code:

```
// request
URL url = new URL(targetURL);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(parameters.getBytes().length));
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.getOutputStream().write(parameters.getBytes());

// response
Reader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int c; (c = rd.read()) >=0;)
    sb.append((char)c);
String response = sb.toString();
// this String is of length 16367 when it should be 16365
```

Does anything jump out as being incorrect here? Note I am not doing any kind of character encoding on either side, should I be when using raw image data?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same encoding everywhere (inclu the DB blob encoding)?  Sounds like an encoding issue on first sight...

Comment: As @Filip says it looks like an encoding issue. Why are you interpreting the binary stream as a String if it's a PNG image?

Comment: I am making absolutely no checks on encoding. It appears the DB blobs are just bytes as per the spec, I will alter server and client to use the same encoding and see what happens

Comment: @cjungel yes that just occurred to me as well, I may just rework it to interpret byte streams as they are

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) to read the byte stream.

```
URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILTQq.png");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/img.png"));

byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

int offset = 0;
int bytes;
while ((bytes = dis.read(buffer, offset, buffer.length)) > 0) {
    fw.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
}
fw.close();
```

Alternatively an instance of `BufferedImage` can be created directly from the `URL` using [ImageIO.read(java.net.URL)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL)).

```
URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILTQq.png");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Comment: That sounds very useful actually, do you know how I would write that to a BufferedImage object rather than to a file?

Comment: Does ImageIO.read() block? This function is always returning null for me, and checking the bytes available on the conn.getInputStream() immediately after the call shows a lot left in the buffer

Comment: It has to block as it performs IO. I updated the answer to use a simpler version of the read method that spares you from managin streams directly and included a link to java api docs.